# JS событие .on("click") в паре с .filter .attr (оптимизация)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, который добавляет переменную id в URL браузера при клике на кнопку.

При клике на кнопку, меняется активный айтем. (Всего их 3 с уникальными ID).

Суть в том, что приходится два раза кликнуть на кнопку, чтобы изменился активный айтем и ID в строке браузера.

**В следствии этого, происходит всё так, что при клике, активный айтем с ID - 3, а записывается в строку ID предыдущего айтема (т.е. ID - 2). А при первом клике, в строку браузера вообще ничего не записывается.**

[Пример можно посмотреть и тут.](https://jsfiddle.net/29oy46y2/1/)

```
<button class="button"></button>

<div class="item" data-id="1">item1</div>
<div class="item active" data-id="2">item2</div>
<div class="item" data-id="3">item3</div>

$(".button").on("click", function() {
    var id = $('.item').filter('.active').attr('data-id');
    history.pushState({foo: 'bar'}, 'Title', '/?id=' + id);
});
```

Comment: А что насчет добавления в вопрос [минимального и самодостаточного примера](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), воспроизводящего проблему?

Comment: я добавил код https://jsfiddle.net/29oy46y2/1/, может будет понятнее

Comment: @DemianShumilov, почему ты думаешь, что 1 клик не срабатывает?

Comment: @Grundy он срабатывает, но в строку записывается ID предыдущего айтема, а не активного. А при первом клике, в строку браузера вообще ничего не записывается.

Comment: приведенный пример должен работать, может у тебя класс active не устанавливается?

Comment: @MikhailM active устанавливается, т.к. это плагин, а не мой код. Активный 3-ий айтем, а фильтрует почему то предыдущий т.е. 2-о (который был активным перед ним).

Comment: @MikhailM а если кликнуть еще раз на айтем (т.е. 2 раз) тогда уже записывается его ID. Т.е. приходится кликнуть 2 раза по айтему, чтобы записался действующий ID (активный), а не предыдущий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел проблему, она заключалась в том, что плагин который я использовал дублировал еще одну секцию с теми же классами и активным айтемом.